# Need help in understanding "factor" function - factor(1 * (tmpd > 80), labels = c("cold","hot"))

Tags: r, dplyr

I came across a command that showcased use of the `mutate` function as follows:

`chicago = mutate(chicago, tempcat = factor(1 * (tmpd > 80), labels = c("cold","hot")))`

I need help in understanding how the `factor` function works in the example above when used along with `mutate`.

Comment: Can you be more specific what exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmpd > 80` takes the `tmpd` column and produces a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, depending on whether the temperature was greater or less than 80.

The expression `1 * (tmpd > 80)` performs an *implicit numerical conversion* on this logical vector, equivalent to `as.numeric(tmpd > 80)`, so it will change all the `FALSE` values to `0` and the `TRUE` values to `1`. So now you have a bunch of `0`s for "cold" and `1`s for "hot".

But instead of leaving these as numbers, we attach labels to them. We do this by using the function `factor`, passing our expression `1 * (tmpd > 80)` as the first argument, and the vector of labels `c("cold", "hot")` as the second argument. Therefore the expression:

```r
factor(1 * (tmpd > 80), labels = c("cold","hot"))
```

creates a vector of class `factor`, which will contain the label `hot` if the temperature was greater than 80, and a label of `cold` otherwise.

Putting this inside `mutate` simply allows us to tell R that we wish to add this vector as a column called `tempcat` to the data frame `chicago`

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation, it indeed helped in understanding the entire command.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...